# Angular ng-repeat. Looping through the letters in string

Tags: angularjs, string, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'va just started learning Angular and can't manage an issue with `ng-repeat`.

I want to display every letter from input in a single `span` element. I tried many ways but nothing works.

[Here's my code on codepen](http://codepen.io/Arkej/pen/NRNBPj)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

Each letter will be printed in different span.

[solution](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes) **of Error: ngRepeat:dupes**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  
});
```

```css
.center-block {
  float: none;
}

input {
  margin: 20px;
}

span:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">

  <div class="col-sm-10 center-block text-center">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type to search..." ng-model="word" />

    <div ng-repeat="letter in word.split('') track by $index">
      <span> {{ letter }} </span>
    </div>
    <br/><br/> If you want to split the word by line <br/><br/>
    <div ng-repeat="letter in word.split(' ') track by $index">
      <span> {{ letter }} </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was exactly I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Arkej : no problem, glad to see that it helped you :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to reference the alias *Letter* as opposed to *Word*

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">

  <div class="col-sm-10 center-block text-center">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type to search..." ng-model="word" />

    <div ng-repeat="letter in word.split('') track by $index">
      <span> {{letter }} </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### EDIT

Apparently what is happening is `word.split('')` is not allowing any duplicates.

`"thisisatest".split('')` if this is input into the console, it splits you expect it to. I dont understand why `word.split('')` is removing duplicates. Type a string with unique chars into your codepen and it will display correctly.

#### EDIT

per *p2.* answer the `track by $index` tracks all duplicates. which fixes the issue. The split is resulting in duplicate items in an array and without `track by $index` angular is just not displaying the duplicates

Comment: I had `letter` but don't know why I saved it having `word` instead. Sorry for mistake.  But ad rem: `letter` also doesn't work. It displays only first three letters and then stop.

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 3):

You should also be using `track by $index` with `ng-repeat` to deal with `Duplicate Key in Repeater`

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">

  <div class="col-sm-10 center-block text-center">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type to search..." ng-model="word" />

    <div ng-repeat="letter in word.split('') track by $index">
      <span> {{letter }} </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good call on the `track by $index`.

Comment: Thank you, I believe in ES6 it is no longer needed to split, because strings are iterable, so just tracking by index is enough.